# random feedback in web application

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, web-applications

We show feedback on our application, but we want to show only 10% of users only. 
For Ex: if total users are 1000 and feedback should be shown only to 100 users.

Is there any idea an logic to implement it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to display randomly or fetch record randomly???? This is important

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `random` method:

```
if(Math.random()<0.1) {
    // show feedback
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, Colin will personally drive to your office and fix it!

Comment: Indeed, it is 98 and ¾ percent guaranteed!

Answer (score 0):

In you database you can have query like

```
SELECT TOP X PERCENT select list
FROM TableName
```

And this way you can fetch only 10% of records from DB and show them on the feedback module.

Hope this is what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I have found useful before is to "label" some users at the start of the session (randomly according to your required distribution). Then record in detail everything the labelled users do with your application. Any feedback they give can then be put in context. As for the mechanism, I would go with a Filter for the initial session labelling and then show an unobtrusive bar at the top of the screen for the labelled users which prompts them (nicely) to give feedback. Make sure the bar has a close button.

Answer (score 0):

This code generates a random number from 0 to 9 and if the randomnumber is 0 (10% chance), then, you can add the feedback code.

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
if (randomnumber == 0)
{  
   // do something
}
```

Comment: erm - why is this any better than testing whether `random()<0.1` ?

Comment: oops.. by the time I posted there are many more answers .. this is almost same as ColinE's solution

Comment: yes.. agreed. Updates are too fast at stackoverflow.. see, i got your comment by the time I type mine :). sorry abt that

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really need it to be EXACTLY 10%, rather than approximately 10%, you could keep a static counter variable that you increment every time a new session starts. When it hits 10, ask the user for feedback and reset the counter to 1.

However, you'll likely need to synchronize access to the variable to prevent requests on different threads manipulating it at once, and this might be a performance bottleneck if you are processing a lot of requests.

Unless you have a good reason, it's probably a lot easier to go with the random number method others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think this through - down the road, you might wish that you did something more than just "display to 10% randomly".

If you are talking about an application that uses authenticated users, and if there is any potential need at all to analyze/understand the response of that 10%, then you ought to do the following:

1. Create a new column or table in your database which assigns each user to either be in (true) or out (false) for your feedback display
2. Use that as the basis for your query to determine to whom you show the message
3. Make sure that the result of that feedback request written back to your database.